# removing quotation marks from responsetext property

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am trying to remove quotation marks from the `responseText` property of a `XMLHttpRequest` object.

My output is :

```
"[{"data":[[0,28]],"label":"Atyc-1"},{"data":[[0,13]],"label":"Atyc-10"},{"data":[[0,16]],"label":"Atyc-11"},{"data":[[0,17]],"label":"Atyc-2"},{"data":[[0,5]],"label":"Atyc-3"}]"
```

what I need is:

```
[{"data":[[0,28]],"label":"Atyc-1"},{"data":[[0,13]],"label":"Atyc-10"},{"data":[[0,16]],"label":"Atyc-11"},{"data":[[0,17]],"label":"Atyc-2"},{"data":[[0,5]],"label":"Atyc-3"}]
```

Comment: @gdoron Why I used blockquote was, the code was a single line and the length was too much.

Comment: Did you try using `substring`?

Comment: Try something like `responseText.substring(1,responseText.length -1)`

Comment: Are you sure the quotes are really there and are not just being added by your debug tool (e.g. Firebug console)?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, actually I override your edit without even seeing it, anyway, it was really unreadable with the blockquote.

Comment: @gdoron LoL Okay. That's fine.

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

**Explanation**:

It's a JSON response, which means the server is responding with JSON format. In order to use it properly in JavaScript, you need to parse the string as JSON using the `JSON.parse()` function. That will convert the JSON object to the response you need.

Comment: need more explanation

Comment: Its a JSON response, which means the server is responding with JSON format. In order to use it properly in 
JavaScript, you need to parse the string as JSON using the `JSON.parse()` function. That will convert the JSON object to the response you need.

Answer (score 5):

```
responsetext.substring(1, responsetext.length - 1);
```

This will return the string with the first and last characters removed.

Answer (score 3):

If you see the output in the console, which it's seems you are, those quotes are only to indicate it's a string.

```
console.log("You see!"); // "You see!"
alert("You see!"); // You see!
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// Considering it is stored in strJSON variable...
strJSON.substring(1, strJSON.length - 1)
```

Comment: Careful... `JSON` is actually a native object. Could be confusing, even with the comment.

Comment: @FelixKling Done. Please check. :)